# Compare a list of lists and group duplicates into a new list in Python

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to python. This is what I'm trying to do...

I have a list of keywords, and each keyword in the list has a list of 10 URLs (sites that rank on the first page of Google for that keyword).

I'd like to check the list of URLs for a given keyword against all the other lists of URLs for the other keywords in my list and group keywords that share 3 or more URLs into a new list with each other.

Whenever 3 or more URLs are shared between keywords, a new group should be created and these keywords should be added to a new list.

Here's the direction I think I should go as a total python noob:

```
keyword1_rankings =[url1, url2, url3, url4, url5, url6, url7, url8, url9, url10]

cluster1 = []

for urls in keyword1_rankings if >=3 urls == urls in keyword2_rankings + cluster1.
```

I know this is atrocious to those more experienced in python, but I'm less than a week into python so go easy on me. Lol

Any pointers on the right direction are very much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: BTW, it is not called `keyword`, as far as I know you should call it `variables`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to keep your keywords as `dict` like:

```py
rankings = {
    'key1': ['url1', 'url2', ...],
    'key2': ['url1', 'url2', ...]
}
```

After that, you can do sth like:

```py
import itertools


all_urls = list(itertools.chain(*rankings.values()))

duplicate_urls = []

for url in rankings['key1']:
    if all_urls.count(url) >= 4:
        duplicate_urls.append(url)
```

Pay attention i compared to 4, because we have our selected key urls in `all_urls` again

Comment: Thanks Amin! But won't this create just one new group or cluster of keywords called duplicate_urls? How do I generate multiple clusters in the event I'm scanning a large list of keywords? For example, key1 and key2 may have some duplicate rankings and be grouped into duplicate_urls, but what if key563 and key1032 also share urls?